# Concurrent read/write buffer in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, locking

I am trying to implement a read/write buffer class where it can be able to support multiple writers and readers, and the reader can read the buffer simultaneously while the writer is writing the buffer. Here's my code, and so far I haven't seen any issue, but I am not 100% sure if this is thread-safe or if there's any better approach.

```
public class Buffer{
       private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
       private Random random = new Random();

       public void read(){
            try{
                lock.readLock().lock();
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
            } finally{
                lock.readLock().unlock();
            }
       }
       public void write(){
            try{
                lock.writeLock().lock();
                sb.append((char)(random.nextInt(26)+'a'));
            } finally{
                lock.writeLock().unlock();
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [codereview.se] would be a better place for that kind of question...

Comment: You should probably unlock in a finally block

Comment: @assylias but what am i trying to catch in my try block ?

Comment: you don't need a catch: `try {yourCode()} finally {unlock();}` - cf the example in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: @user1389813 who knows? its nice to know that whatever happens, the lock will be released.

Comment: just updated the code...I am also wondering if it's okay to use StringBuilder as it's not thread-safe.

Comment: Your StringBuilder is protected by the lock(s), so it is safe.

Comment: What if I make it volatile ?

Comment: No need for volatile. You are only accessing the StringBuilder while having the locks aquired. You won't have visibility issues here. Your class is fine the way it is now.

Comment: As I note in my answer, I see no problems with the code as is. Access to StringBuilder is properly protected.  Java designers did not make it thread safe because 1) wanted StringBuilder to be fast and 2) expected that accessing a StringBuilder would be part of a larger task which would itself be thread-safe.

Comment: Also System.out.println() is synchronized, so no problems from that either.  I believe that covers pretty much everything :-)  The answer is that you are safe and your code is 100% fine wrt thread safety.

Comment: The code doesn't support multiple writers - supporting multiple writes would be very tricky.

Comment: @Scorpion what do you mean by saying very tricky ?

Comment: I am tempted to say, give it a try. Multiple concurrent writes cannot always succeed - refer concurrent hash map, for conflicting writes which one should be preserved?

Comment: @Scorpion for conflicting writes on the same block isn't always First come first serve ?

Comment: First of all, I just noticed that the code supposedly allows the possibility that "the reader can read the buffer simultaneously while the writer is writing the buffer". It does not!  If you have cores 1 to 3 of your processor executing the reading code (3 reader threads), core 4 executing a writer thread cannot proceed with writing but will have to block (and possibly switch to another thread).  However, this quite a normal thing when you have a shared read/write resource.  SQL locks work in the exact same way under the hood of SQL servers.

Comment: As for the question to @Scorpion, it is covered in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No problem with multi-threading safety whatsoever! The read and write locks protect access to the StringBuilder and the code is clean and easy to read.

By using ReentrantReadWriteLock you are actually maximising you chance of achieving higher degrees of concurrency, because multiple readers can proceed together, so this is a better solution than using plain old synchronised methods.  However, contrary to what is stated in the question, the code does *not* allow a writer to write while the readers are reading.  This is not necessarily a problem in itself though.

The readers acquire a read lock before proceeding.  The writers acquire a write lock before proceeding.  The rules of read locks allow one to be acquired when there is no write lock (but it is OK if there are some read locks i.e. if there are more active readers).  The rules of write locks allow one to be acquired if and only if there are no other locks (no readers, no writers). Thus multiple readers are allowed but only a single writer.

The only change that might be needed would be to change the lock initialisation code to this:

```
private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);
```

As is the original code given in the question does not require the lock to be fair.  With the above change it is guaranteed that "threads contend for entry using an approximately arrival-order policy. When the write lock is released either the longest-waiting single writer will be assigned the write lock, or if there is a reader waiting longer than any writer, the set of readers will be assigned the read lock. When constructed as non-fair, the order of entry to the lock need not be in arrival order." (Taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)

See also the following (from the same source):

ReentrantReadWriteLocks can be used to improve concurrency in some uses of some kinds of Collections. This is typically worthwhile only when the collections are expected to be large, accessed by more reader threads than writer threads, and entail operations with overhead that outweighs synchronization overhead. For example, here is a class using a TreeMap that is expected to be large and concurrently accessed.

```
class RWDictionary {
    private final Map<String, Data>  m = new TreeMap<String, Data>();
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock r = rwl.readLock();
    private final Lock w = rwl.writeLock();

    public Data get(String key) {
        r.lock(); try { return m.get(key); } finally { r.unlock(); }
    }
    public String[] allKeys() {
       r.lock(); try { return m.keySet().toArray(); } finally { r.unlock(); }
    }
    public Data put(String key, Data value) {
        w.lock(); try { return m.put(key, value); } finally { w.unlock(); }
    }
    public void clear() {
        w.lock(); try { m.clear(); } finally { w.unlock(); }
   }
 }
```

The excerpt from the API documentation is particularly performance conscious. In your specific case, I cannot comment on whether you meet the "large collection" criterion, but I can say that outputting to the console is much more time consuming than the thread-safety mechanism overhead.  At any rate, you use of ReentrantReadWriteLocks makes perfect sense from a logical point of view and is perfectly thread safe.  This is nice code to read :-)

Note 1 (answering question about exceptions found in the comments of the original question): 
Taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html
lock() acquires the lock. 
If the lock is not available then the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until the lock has been acquired.

A Lock implementation may be able to detect erroneous use of the lock, such as an invocation that would cause deadlock, and may throw an (unchecked) exception in such circumstances. The circumstances and the exception type must be documented by that Lock implementation.

No indication of such exceptions is given in the relevant documentation for ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock.html) or ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock.html)

Note 2: While access to the StringBuilder is protected by the locks, System.out is not.  In particular, multiple readers may read the value concurrently and try to output it concurrently. That is also OK, because access to System.out.println() is synchronized.

Note 3: If you want to disallow multiple active writers, but allow a writer and one or more readers to be active at the same time, you can simple skip using read locks altogether i.e. delete lock.readLock().lock(); and lock.readLock().unlock(); in your code.  However, in this particular case this would be wrong.  You need to stop concurrent reading and writing to the StringBuilder.

Comment: How will you not block writer acquiring write lock when there is at least one read lock is active ?

Comment: With your code as is, you are giving the writer a chance to access in a thread-safe manner a non-thread-safe resource, the StringBuilder. If you have a reader accessing your StringBuilder as you are modifying its contents, you are no longer thread safe, so I would not go there. I would leave your code as it stands, expect perhaps for adding the fairness bit if that is important to you :-)

Comment: So my code allows the writer to acquire writer lock while there's at least a reader ? so how it work...i don't really get it....the reader won't see the most updating value, correct ?

Comment: two possibilities: N active readers (all writers inactive until readers finish) or 1 active writer (all readers and all other writers inactive until the active writer finishes).

Comment: ok, so which means it can't write and read at the same time, correct ? my question is how would you make it non-blocked for the write while there's at least one reader lock ?

Comment: The idea is: no reading while writing. Writing takes you from a consistent state to another consistent state, but if writing takes 100 instructions to complete and the reader jumped in while the writer has half-way through, the state the reader would be accessing would not necessarily be consistent as the writer would not necessarily have finished updating it and making it consistent again e.g. the reader may jump in the middle of an append() after the StringBuilder updates the variable containing the length of its contents but before actually updating those contents.

Comment: To answer your question "how would you make it non-blocked for the write while there's at least one reader lock ?": there is no way, as read locks are there to make writers stop and wait until the read operation is finished.  But if you want to disallow multiple active writers, but allow a writer and one or more readers to be active at the same time, you can simple skip using read locks altogether i.e. delete lock.readLock().lock(); and lock.readLock().unlock(); in your code :-)  I have updated the answer, so that you can accept it, if that is what you were after.

Answer (score -1):

The description and the code seem to be two different things.  You say in the description that you want to let the readers read while the writer (one at a time I assume) writes.  However you have a lock in your read method too.  So right now you have one, reader or writer at a time accessing your buffer.

If you want to have readers access while there is a writer, remove the lock from the read method.

Comment: ic..so i am wondering if the code is equivalent if I remove all the lock and make the read and write method synchronized

Comment: Its only one reader and one writer at a time as is.  The description says "support multiple writers and readers".

Comment: The readers acquire a read lock before proceeding.  The writers acquire a write lock before proceeding.  The rules of read locks allow one to be acquired when there is no write lock (but it is OK if there are some read locks i.e. if there are more active readers).  The rules of write locks allow one to be acquired if and only if there are no other locks (no readers, no writers). Thus multiple readers are allowed but only a single writer.

Comment: @MiltiadisKokkonidis What about the reverse ? Can a write acquires write lock when there's a read lock ? and by saying read locks allow one to be acquired when there's no write lock...does that mean it's not possible to read while write is writing ?

Comment: Please note that the question was asked again and answered in the comments section of my answer

Comment: Should read the documentation before down voting an answer

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html

"This lock allows both readers and writers to reacquire read or write locks in the style of a ReentrantLock. Readers are not allowed until all write locks held by the writing thread have been released."